# Google maps api for geo-direction for interactive website

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-directions-api

The code is for developing an interactive website for routing directions between given geo coordinates. The javascript, css and html are used for the interactive website creation.

Something is missing in my directions.css file; I don't get the map display as a result. Cannot understand where I went wrong.
The map display does not load. My API key and other code is correct. I just seem to be missing something.

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find Friend</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/directions.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Map for Directions</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="#directions">directions</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article id="scroll-info">
    </article>
    <section id="directions">
        <h2>directions map</h2>
        <button id="get-directions">get directions</button><span id="directions-info"></span>
        <p id="directions-info"></p>
        <article id="directions-map">map should appear here</article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; GoodFriend </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/directions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ey=AIzaSyBmrnTnmbmulMkz8*****LgCJvA3koaE" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript code:**

```
console.info('directions.js loaded');
const directionsInfo = document.querySelector('#directions-info');
const directionsButton = document.querySelector('#get-directions');
directionsButton.addEventListener('click', getLocation);
let directionsService;
let directionsDisplay;
function getLocation(){
    navigator.getLocation.getCurrentPosition(functional(position){
        directionsInfo.innerHTML = 'You appear to be at: ${position.coords.latitude}, ${position.coords.longitude}'
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        initMap(pos);
    });
}
function initMap(location){
    directionsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#directions-map'),{
        center: location,
        zoom: 16
    });
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(directionsMap);
    let destination = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3315303,18.0520829);
    calcRoute(location,destination);
}
function calcRoute(start, destination){
    let request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: destination,
        travelmode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT  //
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
        if(status='OK'){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            let starter = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: start,
                map: directionsMap,
                lable: 'You are here'
            });
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: destination,
                map: directionsMap,
                label: 'You need to reach here..'
            });
        }
    })  
}
```

**Erroneous css code**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html{   scroll-behavior: smooth;}
body{
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
    font-family: "helvetica-neue", "arial", "calibri", _sans-serif;
    color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 1.0);
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
a:link, a:visited{  color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .75);}
a:hover, a:focus{
    color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .95);
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{   color: rgba(44, 147, 118, .75);}
header{
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(min-content, auto);
    padding: 1.2em;
    z-index: 1;
}
header nav{ text-align: right;}
nav{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content, auto));
    grid-gap: 1.2em;
}
nav a{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#scroll-info{
    position: fixed;
    top: 89px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.2em;
    background-color: rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0);
    z-index: 1;
}
section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    padding: 8em 1.2em;
}
p{  max-width: 40em;}
ul{ padding: 0.6em 1.2em 1.2em;}
hr{ margin: 2em 0;}
figure{ transition: opacity 2s;}
figure img{ max-width: 100%;}
#directions-map{
    width: 90vw;
    height: 75vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
    padding: 1.2 em;
}
button{
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0069ed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:  none;
}
button: hover,
button: focus {
    background: #0053ba;
}
button: focus {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}
button: active {
    transform: scale(0.99);
}
footer{
    width:  100vw;
    background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
    padding: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getLocation is undefined
    getLocation .js:10
    EventListener.handleEvent* .js:5

Comment: I made stupid mistakes in the code.. Resolved errors..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you deleted the callback function from the src in the script tag.
It should contain &callback=initMap in the end of the string:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ey=AIzaSyBmrnTnmbmulMkz8*****LgCJvA3koaE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find Friend</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        body {
            background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
            font-family: "helvetica-neue", "arial", "calibri", _sans-serif;
            color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 1.0);
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        a:link,
        a:visited {
            color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .75);
        }

        a:hover,
        a:focus {
            color: rgba(16, 16, 16, .95);
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:active {
            color: rgba(44, 147, 118, .75);
        }

        header {
            width: 100vw;
            background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(min-content, auto);
            padding: 1.2em;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        header nav {
            text-align: right;
        }

        nav {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content, auto));
            grid-gap: 1.2em;
        }

        nav a {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 2em;
        }

        #scroll-info {
            position: fixed;
            top: 89px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 32px;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 0 1.2em;
            background-color: rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        section {
            min-height: 100vh;
            min-width: 100vw;
            padding: 8em 1.2em;
        }

        p {
            max-width: 40em;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0.6em 1.2em 1.2em;
        }

        hr {
            margin: 2em 0;
        }

        figure {
            transition: opacity 2s;
        }

        figure img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        #directions-map {
            width: 90vw;
            height: 75vh;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
            padding: 1.2 em;
        }

        button {
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            margin: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: #0069ed;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
        }

        button: hover,
        button: focus {
            background: #0053ba;
        }

        button: focus {
            outline: 1px solid #fff;
            outline-offset: -4px;
        }

        button: active {
            transform: scale(0.99);
        }

        footer {
            width: 100vw;
            background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
            padding: 1.2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Map for Directions</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="#directions">directions</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article id="scroll-info">
    </article>
    <section id="directions">
        <h2>directions map</h2>
        <button id="get-directions">get directions</button><span id="directions-info"></span>
        <p id="directions-info"></p>
        <article id="directions-map">map should appear here</article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; GoodFriend </p>
    </footer>
    <!-- <script src="js/directions.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ey=AIzaSyBmrnTnmbmulMkz8*****LgCJvA3koaE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    console.info('directions.js loaded');
    const directionsInfo = document.querySelector('#directions-info');
    const directionsButton = document.querySelector('#get-directions');
    directionsButton.addEventListener('click', getLocation);
    let directionsService;
    let directionsDisplay;
    function getLocation() {
        navigator.getLocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            directionsInfo.innerHTML = 'You appear to be at: ${position.coords.latitude}, ${position.coords.longitude}'
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            initMap(pos);
        });
    }
    function initMap(location) {
        directionsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#directions-map'), {
            center: location,
            zoom: 16
        });
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(directionsMap);
        let destination = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3315303, 18.0520829);
        calcRoute(location, destination);
    }
    function calcRoute(start, destination) {
        let request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: destination,
            travelmode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT  //
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status = 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                let starter = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: start,
                    map: directionsMap,
                    lable: 'You are here'
                });
                let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: destination,
                    map: directionsMap,
                    label: 'You need to reach here..'
                });
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```